# Custom permalink load template

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, action-filter

I created functions below to customize the permalink of a specific category. Everything is working right!

When accessing the post with this permalink example.com.br/negocios/name-post everything is ok.

But if I access these same posts through example.com.br/name-post it also loads, being that it was for 404 or redirected to the created permalink.

```
add_filter( 'pre_post_link', 'idinheiro_custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function idinheiro_custom_permalink( $permalink, $post ){
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $slug = $category[0]->slug;
    $tag = '%postname%';

    if ( !empty($category) && $slug === 'negocios' ) {
        $permalink = "/$slug/$tag";
    }

    return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'idinheiro_custom_rewrite_rules' );
function idinheiro_custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $new_rules = [
      '^negocios/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]',
    ];

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;

    return $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```